# Problem with generating pdf in texmaker

Tags: pdf, compiling

I am trying to compile a latex file on texmaker 5.0.4 in Mac OS Catalia 10.15.6. I have all the required files MacTex files and I have made sure the preference setting in texmaker is ok. When I am compiling, it is always giving me two errors and no pdf file is being generated:

- PDF version cannot be changed after data is written to the PDF file.
- Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
  I have tried adding \RequirePackage{pdf14} at the beginning of the preamble and also closing Acrobat Reader. Nothing has worked. It is only a problem in my new Mac that I am using for the last week. The compilation works fine with the exact same setting in my old mac with texmaker 5.0.3 and Mac OS Catalia 10.15.6.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

My preamble is as follows:

```
%\RequirePackage{pdf14}
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article} %by Mehmet
%\documentclass[opre,nonblindrev,copyedit]{informs3} %by Han
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage{ulem} %%the effect of deleteing words/sentences
\usepackage{graphicx}%for subfigure added by Han
\usepackage{subfigure}%for subfigure added by Han
\usepackage{booktabs}%for table cmidrule command added by Han
\setstretch{1.6}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.6in}\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{mypred}{Prediction}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.3cm,bmargin=2.4cm,lmargin=2.2cm,rmargin=2.2cm}
% Natbib setup for author-year style
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[final]{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name=Mehmet, color=purple]{MG}
\definechangesauthor[name=Saibal, color=red]{SR}
\definechangesauthor[name=Han, color=blue]{HZ}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\ep{\epsilon}%%%added by Han
 \def\uep{\underline{\ep}}%%%added by Han
 \def\oep{\overline{\epsilon}}%%%added by Han
 \def\bc{\bar{c}}%%%added by Han
 \def\BIBand{and}%
\pdfminorversion 3
%% Setup of theorem styles. Outcomment only one.
%% Preferred default is the first option.

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{soul}

% Theorem environments
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{main}{Main~Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}%%added by Han
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}%%%added by Han
\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{\S\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\lemref}[1]{Lemma~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\bysame}{\mbox{\rule{3em}{.4pt}}\,}
\newcommand{\hlcyan}[1]{{\sethlcolor{cyan}\hl{#1}}}
\newcommand{\hlred}[1]{{\sethlcolor{red}\hl{#1}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you load the `geometry` package twice, and why do you have both `\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}` *and* `\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.3cm,bmargin=2.4cm,lmargin=2.2cm,rmargin=2.2cm}`?

Comment: What's the purpose of `\pdfminorversion 3`?